# Pandas Oracle query gives "ORA-00911: invalid character"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

Hello I am trying to execute the following Oracle Query. I confirmed i can successfully connect to the database using cx_Oracle but my query is not executing. This is a large table and i am trying to limit the number of rows to 10

```
query1 = """
select *
  from
(select *
   from some_table
  )
where rownum < 10;
""" 

df_ora1 = pd.read_sql(query1, con=connection1)
```

I am getting the following error but cant figure out what the invalid character is!

DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon from the SQL statement.  Semi-colons are not part of SQL.

```
query1 = """ select * from (select * from some_table ) where rownum < 10 """
```